# Why does a shorthand if in an and statement without parentheses evaluate incorrectly?

Tags: c#

We are going to use a simple example (I had a much more complicated piece of code evaluating incorrectly) that will demonstrate this issue as clearly as possible.

My question is why this evaluates incorrectly until the parentheses are added?

I have resolved the issue by adding the parentheses around the shorthand conditional, it was just a pain to locate the issue, because it read properly to me.

```
Console.WriteLine(false && true ? false : true);
```

Expected Result: False.

Actual Result: True.

Now lets add parentheses:

```
Console.WriteLine(false && (true ? false : true));
```

Expected Result: False.

Actual Result: False.

In my mind, the first part of the evaluation is false, so it shouldn't even bother to evaluate the latter part of the && operation. What causes this behavior?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Comment: && has higher precedence than `?`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=vs-2019

Comment: To understand why your logic breaks down, imagine the code was `Console.WriteLine(false && true ? "False1" : "True2");`. What would you expect that code to write to the console **and why**? `&&` doesn't mean 'don't do **anything else** to the right if `false`'. Otherwise my example code could write a string **or a boolean** (which clearly isn't possible).

Comment: It is not incorrect your expectation is. false && true evaluates to false, and runs the false side of your ternary which says true.

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to Stuartd & MjWills.

The explanation is the order of execution for the Conditional AND vs the conditional operations.

Because of this, the execution looks something like this:

`False && True` = `False` -> `False ? False : True` = `True`.

Much appreciated!